# JQuery | Dialog: Link disappears after click

Tags: jquery, dialog

when I open a dialog box onclick the link disappears.

```
    function flugzeitenAnzeigen(myUrl) {
    $('.' + myUrl).load('http://www.mydomain.com/Flugzeiten_Anzeigen.aspx?flugid=' + myUrl +'').dialog({ width: 510, modal: true, title: 'Ihre voraussichtlichen Flugdaten' });
};

<a href="#" id="GridView1_ctl04_flugzeitenAnzeigen" title="Flugzeiten anzeigen" class="702811" onclick="javascript: flugzeitenAnzeigen(702811);">anzeigen</a>
```

The class 702811 is generated dynamically in a grid.

What can I do? thx in advance

Comment: what does myUrl equals to ?

and what do you mean dissapears? you are makeing a dialog of it...
no?..

Comment: @guy_schaller, the myUrl is being passed in from the event handler call in the href onclick declaration. That's the least of the problems here.

Comment: @guy: I just want the link to open a dialog. It does, but when I close the dialog, the link has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a function to be called when the anchor tag has loaded, i.e. the load event. That function does not cause the hyperlink to load a page. The dialog function identifies the element on the page that will be the dialog that's displayed, you've pointed it to a hyperlink.

I think you need to look at [jquerytools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) and the overlay control there, that's much more what you are trying to achieve I believe.

Comment: thx, you were right. I changed it to 

                                                        <a href="#" id="GridView1_ctl05_flugzeitenAnzeigen" onclick="javascript: flugzeitenAnzeigen(703020);">anzeigen</a>
                                                        <div title="Flugzeiten anzeigen" class="703020"></div>